# sbteclipse 2.4.0 doesn't work with sbt 0.13.1 and Scala 2.10.3, on Fedora 20 XFCE

Tags: scala, sbt, fedora, scala-2.10, sbteclipse

I have a problem where my Scala project will not build in sbt 0.13.1 and Scala 2.10.3 unless I DO NOT try to add the sbteclipse plugin (2.4.0).

I recently switched from Linux Mint 14 Xfce to Fedora 20 Xfce. When I was on Linux Mint 14, I developed a small RESTful service using Scala, Akka, Spray, and Slick, building using sbt. After installing Fedora 20, I installed all the packages necessary to resume work on that REST service. To that end, I ran

```
yum install -y java
yum install -y scala
yum install -y sbt
```

This installed OpenJDK 1.7.0_51, Scala 2.10.3, and sbt 0.13.1.

When my `plugins.sbt` contains the line

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.4.0")
```

running `sbt` from the command line generates the following error:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3: configuration not found in org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3: 'compile'
```

This is a problem whether the `plugins.sbt` is located in `<projectfolder>/project`, or in `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins`.

When I comment-out the

```
// addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.4.0")
```

line from the plugins.sbt, the build functions normally.

I recreated the problem using a simple test project that just creates a single Scala class with a one-line print statement. The problem continues to occur independently of whatever other plugins, repositories, or library dependencies I define in the plugins.sbt and build.sbt files.

The simple test project is located at [testproject on Github](https://github.com/crimsonpig/ai-flightplans-manager/tree/master/testproject)

The REST service is located at [airport-web on Github](https://github.com/crimsonpig/ai-flightplans-manager/tree/master/airport-web)

Please note that the REST service has commented-out the addSbtPlugin...sbteclipse line in plugins.sbt.

Comment: Not just Fedora 20 XFCE, but also Fedora 20 GNOME. This does not happen with Debian Sid GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to be sure witch sbt version you are using, You might have an unexpected version in your path. You can check it with:

```
sbt sbt-version
```

One you know what is your version you can select the right version.

- sbt version     -> sbteclipse version
- 0.13 and up......-> 2.4.0
- 0.12 ...............     -> 2.1.2
- 0.11.3..............     -> 2.1.1
- 0.11.2..............     -> 2.0.0

Comment: One thing you can do is to factor out the tooling into ~/.sbt.  See one way to do that here: https://github.com/jkleckner/dotsbt/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I finished for using last versions of everything:

sbt: 0.13.2
sbteclipse: 2.5.0

I removed all eclipse configuration files for my project (.classpath,.cache,.project,...)
I removed all folders generated by previous versions of sbt (target, bin,..)
I also removed all java libraries from home ~/.ivy2 to avoid possible conflicts with previously downloaded versions

Then I compiled as : sbt compile
Then I add plugins.sbt to the /project folder and call again as: sbt eclipse.

No more errors appeared and I succeeded to import from eclipse. I'm not sure about what was wrong because i didn't find anything on the web. But this worked for me.